# How to use webrtc to get the application list of shared screen in current computer？

Tags: javascript, webrtc

We need to use our own UI interface to display the current computer screen sharing applications, and then through webrtc, select the application to share.

But using `navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia()` will use the browser's default pop-up box to display the current shareable applications. How to get the list of shareable screen application information and apply it to our UI?

[image: default pop-up of webrtc]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  This isn't possible, due to the security implications.

You have to work with what the browser gives you.  At best, you could make a browser extension that calls out to a native application, which could send this data back to your web application.